# How to show database values to textbox on selected combobox. I am usinga constructors and not using a mysqlcommand,reader and adapter

Tags: vb.net

I am only use contructors to have a much more control than the other video tutorial that i saw. i am new on this kind of technique and code. The values on the combobox is thought by my professor and i now i am confused on how to do the textbox that will shows it values when selecting the combobox i really need to know it works without using a sqlcommand,sqldatareader and sqladapter because this 3 is what im used to.

```
Imports SystemALib

Public Class formStart
    Inherits AForm2


    Private _PK_delete As Integer
    Private listDT As DataTable

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        '_MyName = ""
        '_MyTitle = ""
        '_formTitle = ""
    End Sub

#Region "Load / 1Run / Perms"
    Protected Overrides Sub preloading()
        'customloader = My.Resources.logo1_192
        'customloader = My.Resources.loading_ss1
        'iscustomloader = 1
        'customicon = My.Resources.icon1_32
        'iscustomicon = 1
        'iswindowfixed = false
    End Sub

   
    Protected Overrides Sub loadingForm()
        ' _FK_user = myUser.id

        'setBarcodeBox(txtField)
        'setViewerReference(viewer)
    End Sub

    ' para lang syang loading form
    Protected Overrides Sub firstRun()
        'BASE_Dock()
        'lTitle.Text = _MyTitle

        initDB()
        If Not DBConn.testConnection() Then
            Dim dlg As New ADlgConfigMySQL()
            If dlg.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
                DBConn = New ADBConnMySQL(dlg.Server, dlg.UserID, dlg.Password, dlg.Database)

                My.Settings.dbserver = dlg.Server
                My.Settings.dbuser = dlg.UserID
                My.Settings.dbpass = dlg.Password
                My.Settings.dbdatabase = dlg.Database
                My.Settings.Save()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    
    Protected Overrides Sub applyPermissions()
        ' nothing to do here
    End Sub
#End Region


    ' thread, background process
  
#Region "Init"
    Protected Overrides Function initTask() As Boolean
        ' paglalagyan ng data
        listDT = New DataTable()
        With listDT.Columns
            .Add("PK_item", GetType(Integer))
            .Add("Name", GetType(String))
            .Add("Details", GetType(String))
            .Add("UoM", GetType(String))
            .Add("Cost", GetType(Decimal))
        End With

        Return True
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub initDone(result As Boolean)
        If result Then
            loadStart()
        End If
    End Sub
#End Region

   
#Region "Populate"
    Protected Overrides Function loadTask() As Boolean
        Dim q As New ADBQueryMySQL(DBConn)
        Dim row As New ADBClass.dbRow

        q.SQL = "SELECT FROM tmp_item ORDER BY itemname"
        q.execute()

        ' code para i-clear yung current table
        clearDGV(dgvList)
        listDT.Rows.Clear()

        While q.getDBRow(row)
            Dim dtrow As DataRow = listDT.NewRow ' create ka ng bagong row dun sa table mo (hindi pa sya kasali sa table mismo)
            dtrow.Item("PK_item") = row.getValue("PK_item")
            dtrow.Item("Name") = row.getValue("itemname")
            dtrow.Item("Details") = row.getValue("description")
            dtrow.Item("UoM") = row.getValue("unit")
            dtrow.Item("Cost") = row.getValue("cost")
            listDT.Rows.Add(dtrow) 
        End While

        q.close()
        Return True
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub loadDone(result As Boolean)
        If result Then
            dgvList.DataSource = listDT
        End If
    End Sub
#End Region

   
#Region "Save"
    Protected Overrides Function saveTask() As Boolean
        ' nothing to do here
        Dim q As New ADBQueryMySQL(DBConn)


        q.SQL = "DELETE FROM tmp_item WHERE PK_item"
        q.execute()

        If Not q.success Then
            q.close()
            showError(q.errorMsg)
            Return False
        End If
        Return True
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub saveDone(result As Boolean)
        ' nothing to do here
        If result Then
            popInfo("Save OK!")
            loadStart()

        Else
            popError("Save not OK!")
        End If
    End Sub
#End Region

    Private Sub bRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bRefresh.Click
        If Not checkReady() Then Return ' kapag may umaandar na thread, wag ka tutuloy

        loadStart()
    End Sub

    Private Sub bAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bAdd.Click
        If Not checkReady() Then Return

        Dim dlg As New dlgAddItem()
        If dlg.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
            loadStart()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub bEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bEdit.Click
        If Not checkReady() Then Return
        If listDT.Rows.Count <= 0 Or dgvList.SelectedRows.Count <= 0 Then Return

        Dim pk As Integer = dgvList.SelectedRows(0).Cells("PK_item").Value

        Dim dlg As New dlgAddItem(pk)
        If dlg.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
            loadStart()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        If (Not checkReady()) Then Return
        If (dgvList.Rows.Count <= 0 Or dgvList.SelectedRows.Count <= 0) Then Return

        Dim pk As Integer = dgvList.SelectedRows(0).Cells("PK_item").Value


        If Not showConfirm("Please confirm deleting item:" & vbCrLf & pk & vbCrLf & "Continue?") Then Return

        _PK_delete = pk
        saveStart()


    End Sub



    Private Sub btnBuy_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBuy.Click
        FormList.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There's way too much code there. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. Also, please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. What EXACTLY do you expect to happen and what actually does happen?